# clang incompatibility with delayed template parsing, std::filesystem, and precompiled headers?

Tags: c++, templates, cmake, clang++

I have a very large MSVC to clang conversion project that requires delayed template parsing, using the  -fdelayed-template-parsing option in clang.  I also need to use precompiled headers otherwise the compilation is monumentally slow.  Unfortunately, because of a particular include, std::filesystem, the compiler barfs all over me for a very simple case. The simplest case I can illustrate the problem with is as follows.  This works:

```
[root@836b485f209d pch]# cat foobar.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello world\n");
}
[root@836b485f209d pch]# cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(foobar)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17")
add_executable(foobar foobar.cpp)
target_precompile_headers(foobar PUBLIC
        <stdio.h>
        <filesystem>
)
[root@836b485f209d pch]#
```

But the moment I change CMakeLists.txt to include delayed template parsing:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(foobar)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -fdelayed-template-parsing")
add_executable(foobar foobar.cpp)
target_precompile_headers(foobar PUBLIC
        <stdio.h>
        <filesystem>
)
```

The compiler will barf all over me with plenty of errors in stl_algobase.h (this isn't a complete list, just a sample):

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:381:24: error:
      expected '('
                             && __is_pointer<_II>::__value
                                            ^
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:381:25: error:
      '_II' does not refer to a value
                             && __is_pointer<_II>::__value
                                             ^
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:385:40: error:
      non-type template argument is not a constant expression
      return std::__copy_move<_IsMove, __simple,
                                       ^
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:380:18: error:
      default initialization of an object of const type 'const bool'
      const bool __simple = (__is_trivial(_ValueTypeI)
```

Is there anything I can do?  I need the combination of precompiled headers, std::filesystem and delayed template parsing.

Update: I ended up having to modify a lot of code in the projet to to avoid needing delayed template parsing. That avoids the problem, but it's still bugging me that the standard  library doesn't seem to work with delayed template parsing.

Comment: Given that “delayed template parsing” is *not standard* (for the past 21 years), it’s not too surprising that sophisticated standard library code doesn’t work with it.